# How to get the attribute (e.g., title) of an element when clicked on, with Javascript (not jQuery)?

Tags: javascript

I'm exploring some sample code from a book.  The code has a set of thumbnails like this:

```
<div id="thumbnailPane">
  <img src="images/itemGuitar.jpg" alt="guitar" width="301" height="105" 
       title="itemGuitar" id="itemGuitar" />
  <img src="images/itemShades.jpg" alt="sunglasses" width="301" height="88" 
       title="itemShades" id="itemShades" />
  <img src="images/itemCowbell.jpg" alt="cowbell" width="301" height="126" 
       title="itemCowbell" id="itemCowbell" />
  <img src="images/itemHat.jpg" alt="hat" width="300" height="152" 
       title="itemHat" id="itemHat" />
</div>
```

When a thumbnail is clicked, it brings out a larger image with this function:

```
function initPage() {
  // find the thumbnails on the page
  thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbnailPane").getElementsByTagName("img");
  // set the handler for each image
  for (var i = 1; i < thumbs.length; i++) {//CHANGED FROM 0 TO 1
    image = thumbs[i];

    // create the onclick function
    image.onclick = function() {
      // find the image name
      detailURL = 'images/' + this.title + '-detail.jpg';
      document.getElementById("itemDetail").src = detailURL;
      getDetails(this.title);
    }
  }
}
```

I understand how that works.  What I am wondering is whether it would be possible to replicate that with a single hard coded function.  Basically what I'd like is to get the title of a thumbnail when it is clicked with a single common function for all thumbnails that would be called with an `onclick` event handler (`onclick="getImage()"`).

How do I get the `title` or the `id` of the element that was just clicked?

I do not use jQuery, so I need a JS answer please.

EDIT:

I have tried to write a `getImage()` function like this:

```
function getImage(){
  var title = this.title;
  detailURL='images/' + title + '-detail.jpg';
  document.getElementById("itemDetail").src = detailURL;
}
```

This doesn't work.  The value of `var title` is `"undefined"`.

Comment: You should forget the good old inline `onclick` and friends. Use the advanced event handling (`addEventListener`), Luke. It's good for you.

Comment: If you learn the better one first, you will not have bad habits and old methods to unlearn later. One could easily live without ever using inline event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would pass the element to the handler, and define a parameter `getImage`.

```
onclick="getImage(this)"
```

---

Or better, you'd `.call` the handler, so you can still use `this` in `getImage`.

```
onclick="getImage.call(this)"
```

---

But overall, you don't need an inline handler to reuse a function. Just make a named function, and assign it in your JavaScript code. It'll just work.

Comment: How would you write the `getImage(this)` function to get the title?  Something like `getImage(){var title=this.title;...}` doesn't work.

Comment: @JDelage: Using the first code example, you do: `getImage(img){var title = img.title;}` or using the second code example, you do: `getImage(){var title = this.title;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use of event handlers:

```
function clickHandler(){
    var title = this.title;
    ...
}

//assign handler to element
image.addEventListener('click',clickHandler);
```

Comment: most attributes get copied into object properties - it's easier to use `this.title` and `this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where the dependency on `i` or `image` in the function defined in the loop is, so why not just move it out of the loop so they all share the same one?
Here is how I'd write your function

```
function initPage() {
    // remember to use var so you're not defining in the global scope
    var thumbs = document.getElementById('thumbnailPane').getElementsByTagName('img'),
        i = thumbs.length,
        getImage = function getImage() { // onclick function
            // again remember var
            var title = this.title,
                detailURL = 'images/' + title + '-detail.jpg';
            document.getElementById('itemDetail').src = detailURL;
            getDetails( title );
        };
    // Attach to each thumb
    while( i-- ) thumbs[i].addEventListener('click', getImage, false);
}
```

---

Edit
**Q**. Why doesn't the function you tried work using `this.title`?
**A**. This is because `this` means something different depending on how you invoke the function or object using it. Calling your function directly as `getImage()` will set the `this` to `window` (or the caller, and `window.title === undefined`), rather than your `<img>`. You have to make the image invoke `getImage` itself (add as a listener) or use `getImage.call` or `getImage.apply` with your `<img>` as the first arg.